# Giving a single user write permissions

Tags: permissions, users

I want to grant a single user write permissions to a directory owned by root over command line. With chmod, it seems that I can only change the permissions for owner, group and other, not for a specific user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If filesystem is mounted with the `acl` option (default in ext4 in any modern Ubuntu - if not, add it to `/etc/fstab`), you can use `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -m u:USERNAME:r FILENAME
```

would give user USERNAME read access to FILENAME.

Comment: Remember to install `acl` package.

Answer (score 1):

By default in Ubuntu every user belongs to a group with the same name, i.e. hannesh:hannesh.

You can make the folder owned by root:hannesh, and give it permissions like 770 though I see no reason for it to be owned by root if you want the user to be able to write there - why doesn't hannesh:hannesh suit you? Root would be able to write in that folder anyway.

Also have a read about the sticky bit if root creates files in that directory which need to be writeable by the user.