# Make a file with root access only and able to be accessed by another file without using a password

Tags: scripts, sudo, files, root, users

I have two files A and B. I need the contents of A to be accessible only by root, so I have run the command `chmod 000 A`.

Now, I want file B to be able to access file A without asking for the root password. How can I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving a single user write permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62868/giving-a-single-user-write-permissions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

Comment: Hello, Sam Hartwright, did you succeed with this task?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume we have two files `A` and `B`. The both files are located in the home directory of a regular user. The file `A` is owned by `root` and only that user has read permissions as follow:

```bsh
$ cat A                   # output the content of the file
"Test content of file A"

$ chmod 400 A             # change the permissions of file A to read only by the user/owner
$ sudo chown root:root A  # change the ownership of the file to user and :group 'root'

$ ls -l A                 # check the permissions and the ownership, 'stat -c "%a %n" A' to get them in octal
-r-------- 1 root root 24 яну 22 10:17 A

$ sudo cat A              # output the content of the file A, that is ownes by 'root'
"Test content of file A"
```

The file `B` is simple script that outputs the content of `A`, it is owned by the regular user. `B` has executable permissions as follow:

```bsh
$ cat B                   # output the content of the file
#!/bin/bash
cat /home/<user>/A

$ chmod +x B              # add executable permissions to the file for all users

$ ./B                     # execute file B by a regular user
cat: /home/<user>/A: Permission denied

$ sudo ./B                # execute file B with root privileges
[sudo] password for <user>: 
"Test content of file A"
```

To execute the last command above without password we can use `NOPASSWD` directive within the file `/etc/sudoers` or we can create separate file, dedicated to this task, located in `/etc/sudoers.d/` (as it is in the next example). Note, the use of the command [`visudo` is absolutely necessary](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/566421) when you edit files as these. So, run the command:

```bsh
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/no-passwd-A-B
```

Add the following content inside, save and close:

```bsh
<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /home/<user>/A
```

Now you will be able to execute the following command and you will not be asked for a password:

```bsh
$ sudo ./B
"Test content of file A"
```

If you do not want to type `sudo` in front of the command, you can put it inside the script:

```bsh
$ cat B                   # output the content of the file
#!/bin/bash
sudo cat /home/<user>/A

$ ./B
"Test content of file A"
```

---

> **NOTE:** In the [previous version of the answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1111891/2) is described how to add `NOPASSWD` directive in `sudoers` file for a script (file `B` in our case), but, as [@RoVo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/rovo) said, this approach is pretty dangerous, because if the user has write permissions to the file it can make harmful changes inside. Practically the user will be able to do/crash anything.
>
> If you want to use this variant, where the content of `/etc/sudoers.d/no-passwd-A-B` is:
>
> ```bsh
> <user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/<user>/B
> ```
>
> Then for security reasons, change the ownership of the file `B` to root and grant it only read and execute (but not write) permissions for the other users, something like:
>
> ```bsh
> $ chmod 605 B
> $ sudo chown root:root B
>
> $ ls -l B
> -rw----r-x 1 root root 38 яну 22 15:31 B
> ```
>
> Another way to add more security in your system, provided by [@PerlDuck](https://askubuntu.com/users/504066/perlduck), is to have `sudo` check the executable against manipulation:
>
> 1. For this purpose get the sha256sum of the executable file:
>
>    ```bsh
>    $ openssl dgst -binary -sha256 /home/<user>/B | openssl base64
>    sfDELCTNqfrDY9QKzz8Ra2wTnIpFXyyN8sG9JFxUJtA=
>    ```
> 2. Add that sha256sum to the sudoers file like so:
>
>    ```bsh
>     <user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: sha256:sfDEL...xUJtA= /home/<user>/B
>    ```
>
> Then `sudo` will complain if the sha256 of the script doesn't match the value in the sudoers file.

Comment: Isn't it pretty dangerous to add `NOPASSWD` in sudoers file for a script the user has write access ? He can then do pretty much anything without sudo or am I wrong ? So the second solution is to preferred I'd say.

Comment: @RoVo, I think you are right! Probably the second approach is more safe. I will update the answer.

Comment: or make B owned by root and readable by others.

Comment: Thanks for this note @RoVo, I've updated and simplified the answer.

Comment: @RoVo You can have `sudo` check the executable against manipulation: **1)** run `openssl dgst -binary -sha256 /home/<user>/B | openssl base64` and **2)** add that sha256 to the `sudoers` file like so: `<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: sha256:wQ2G5...rHpSM= /home/<user>/B`. Then `sudo` will complain if the sha256 of the script doesn't match the value in the sudoers file.

Comment: That is great, didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: @PerlDuck, great idea. I've added it to the answer ... but probably I'm missing something, because when I changed the content of `B` to `echo "test" > /root/test`, the file change wasn't indicated in any way by the `sudo` command, and I successfully executed `sudo ./B`. Any ideas?

Comment: What does "successfully executed" mean? Without password? I think the sha256 check only works for the exact command as given in the sudoers file, i.e. `sudo /home/user/B` and not `sudo ./B`. Cannot verify right now (am on my mobile).